# Alternative way to define bootRun task in Gradle doesn't work

Tags: gradle, groovy

I usually define tasks in `Gradle` (using `Groovy`) like `tasks.withType(Type)`; e.g.: `tasks.withType(JavaCompile)`, `tasks.withType(Test)`, etc.

Now, I want to do the same with some provided `Spring Boot` tasks, namely: `bootRun` and `bootStartScripts`, but `Gradle` cannot find it.

I know it's silly and I could get away just by using `bootRun` and `bootStartScripts`, but I would like to understand why those cannot be configured/defined in such way.

Comment: Can't you just do `tasks.withType(BootRun)` (you'll probably need to import `org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun`) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/run/BootRun.html

Comment: My bad :/ ...that's what I did initially and it didn't work. Later on I had to restart the IDE because it got into some weird state. Now I tried again and it worked fine...I should have ran in the CLI to start with. I was blindly trusting the IDE ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess with *define* you mean *configure*, because `withType` can only be used to configure existing tasks. It takes a task type (a class) and a closure that can be used to configure **all** available tasks of that type. This needs to be considered, because a project may contain multiple tasks of the same type that should actually do completely different things. Whether to configure all those tasks or just a specific one is important!

To pass the task type to the method `withType` you need to know the name of the class implementing the task type. This name is not necessarily related to the name(s) of the actual task(s). For the tasks `test` and `compileJava` of the Gradle Java Plugin those classes are [`org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html) and [`org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/JavaCompile.html). Since those classes are provided by Gradle, they are automatically imported and can be referenced via their simple names `Test` and `JavaCompile`. But the Spring Boot Plugin is a third-party plugin, so the classes need to be referenced by their full names.

The task `bootStartScripts` from your question is of type `CreateStartScript`, that is provided by Gradle. Therefore it can be configured like this:

```
tasks.withType(CreateStartScripts) {
    // configure
}
```

The task `bootRun` is of type [`org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/run/BootRun.html), that is provided by the Spring Boot Plugin. So you need to specify the full name:

```
tasks.withType(org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun) {
    // configure
}
```